# Make column height same

Tags: html, css

I need your help on this. I would like to make the filter section the same as the result section. However, I am having a hard time on how to make it the same as in the results. I've also been reading the article on [Equal Height Columns with Cross-Browser CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

Below are the codes which I've done. Note that the height is dependent on the results pane or on the filters pane.

```css
    #SearchAll tr td {
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    #SearchAllPane {
      background: grey;
    }
    
    #container1 {
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    #container2 {
      float: left;
    }
    
    #col1 {
      float: left;
      width: 160px;
      background: white;
      padding-left: 10px;
      height: calc(100% - 54px);
    }
    
    #col2 {
      float: left;
      width: 20px;
      /*background: grey;*/
    }
    
    #col2 img {
      width: 18px;
      height: 18px;
    }
    
    .FilterItem {
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
    
    #ResultTable {
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    
    .ResultRow {
      height: 30px;
      line-height: 30px;
      background-color: green;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<table id="SearchAll">
      <tr>
        <td id="SearchAllPane">
          <div id="container2">
            <div id="container1">
              <div id="col1">
                <div class="FilterItem">
                  Filter 1
                </div>
                <div class="FilterItem">
                  Filter 1
                </div>
                <div class="FilterItem">
                  Filter 1
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="col2">
                <img src="http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/font-awesome/svg/angle-left.svg" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    
        </td>
        <td>
          <table id="ResultTable">
            <tr>
              <td class="ResultRow">Results</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="ResultRow">Results</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="ResultRow">Results</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="ResultRow">Results</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="ResultRow">Results</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="ResultRow">Results</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Here's the link of what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/arw5n4qb/

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is pretty complicated, which is going to make styling it harder; here's a simple version. (Run the snippet below, or see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3q253011/).) The important part is: one div contains the left side content, one contains the right side, and both of those are set to `display: table-cell`. Their parent container is set to `display: table;`. Sibling elements set to `display: table-cell` will automatically sit next to each other without wrapping. They'll also match their heights, so both will be as tall as the tallest content.

If you want the filters and rows to be vertically centered with each other, you can add `vertical-align: middle` to those sibling divs or to their parent. Otherwise, as you can see, they default to aligning their content along the top.

```css
.container {
  display: table; /* important */
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.filters,
.results {
  display: table-cell; /* also important */
  width: 200px;
}

.filters {
  background: white;
}

/* the rest is cosmetic -
 * change these styles if needed */
.filter, .result {
  line-height: 2;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.result {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="filters">
    <div class="filter">Filter 1</div>
    <div class="filter">Filter 2</div>
    <div class="filter">Filter 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <div class="result">Result row</div>
    <div class="result">Result row</div>
    <div class="result">Result row</div>
    <div class="result">Result row</div>
    <div class="result">Result row</div>
    <div class="result">Result row</div>
    <div class="result">Result row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```